# properties variable setting with velocity

Tags: velocity, properties-file

During my searching, I would like a confirmation :

I would like to set a properties variable to velocity variable kind of :

```
#set($infos.get("trackerData").get(0).get("info_suivi")=tracking.status)
```

My properties file contains :

```
tracking.status.liv=livr&eacute;
tracking.status.env=envoy&eacute;
tracking.status.cmd=command&eacute;
tracking.status.err=erreur
tracking.status.ann=annul&eacute;
```

and $infos is a map

Is It the correct syntax?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The main usecase for `#set` is to assign a value to a variable:

```
#set ($variable = 'value')
```

A secondary usecase, which only works in more recent versions of Velocity, is to assign values to object properties, **if there is a setter for those properties** (i.e. the object is a simple bean):

```
#set ($object.property = 'value')
## Same as:
$object.setProperty('value')
```

Through some Velocity magic, this also works for maps and indexed lists:

```
#set ($map = {})
#set ($map.key = 'value')
$map
## Same as:
$map.put('key', 'value')
## ...except that it doesn't print the previous value stored in the map

#set ($array = ['original'])
#set ($array[0] = 'changed')
$array
## Same as:
$array.set(0, 'changed')
## ...except that it doesn't print the previous value stored in the array
```

But it will never be able to assign a value to another value. `$infos.get("trackerData").get(0).get("info_suivi")` ends with a getter, so it will return a value. Assigning a value to another value is impossible in almost all programming languages.

Second, `#set ($something = tracking.status)` is invalid no matter what `$something` is. If you try that it will give a syntax error. Velocity doesn't have any native feature for anything except what's provided by the very few keywords it knows: `#foreach` for iterating over variables, `#if` for testing variables, `#set` for changing variables, and a few others that don't really deal with variables. Is the properties file supposed to be used as a localization resource? Then you need to load them either in a [`ResourceBundle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) or a [`Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) object, place that object in the `VelocityContext`, and then use it by calling methods of the Java class used to get values based on a key. That's [`getString('key')`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getString%28java.lang.String%29) for a `ResourceBundle`, and simply `get('key')` for a `Properties` object.

Third, the properties file has keys that have `tracking.status` as a prefix, `tracking.status` itself is not an actual property. How do you get the actual status? Are you actually trying to get the message behind the key obtained by prefixing the value behind the `info_suivi` property with `tracking.status.`? Then, assuming that the properties file is exposed through `$messages`, this should work:

```
$messages.getString("tracking.status.${infos.get('trackerData').get(0).get('info_suivi')}")
```

If you want to store this in a variable instead of printing it directly:

```
#set ($infoSuivi = $messages.getString("tracking.status.${infos.get('trackerData').get(0).get('info_suivi')}"))
```